# Why does this java casting fail

Tags: java, casting

I have three classes.

`Person <-- Student <-- GradStudent`, where `<--` means extends (ie, GradStudent extends Student, Student extends Person)

`Person person = new Student(); // this is perfectly legal`

```
GradStudent gradStudent = (GradStudent) person;
System.out.println(gradStudent); // java.lang.ClassCastException here
```

Why? Our **person** variable is a Student, and we could do **Student s = new GradStudent()**, and so why is this not working?

Similarly if I do

```
Student student = new Student();
GradStudent aGradStudent = (GradStudent) student;
System.out.println(aGradStudent); // same error here
```

Why can we do **Student s = new GradStudent()**, but we cannot do **Student student = new Student()**, and THEN **GradStudent aGradeStudent  = (GradStudent) student**

Comment: Upcasting is always allowed in Java and it's implicit and also because a sub-class it's different from a sub-type which respect the substitution principle.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's not safe to say that every instance of `Person` or `Student` is also an instance of `GradStudent`. But every instance of `GradStudent` or `Student` is also an instance of `Person`.
You can always abstract to a higher level of the hierarchy, but not in the other direction.

Comment: What I dont understand is that how is casting any different from just declaring `Student student = new GradStudent()`?

Comment: Because this is a declaration which has static type Student and dynamic type GradStudent which is upcasted. See dynamic dispatch in Java for more details.

Comment: In this context it's not: You can do `Student student = new GradStudent();` **and** could cast `Student student = (Student) gradStudent;`. But the latter wouldn't make sense, because you don't need that cast. Every `GradStudent` **is** a `Student`. There's nothing to cast.